# Simple way to add a caption to an image in a ColorBox lightbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a very simple ColorBox gallery setup just like the examples. Simple  tags with the same group name as their class. I would like an easy way to display a caption or title for each image. Ideally just taken from the images alt attribute or something similar. I have found some solutions that involve calling a title() function but I don't understand how to implement them. Thanks!

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: @JasperMogg I had a hard time replicating the lightbox in jsFiddle, but this does illustrate the basic setup:  http://jsfiddle.net/z56YN/   Original link to usage here:  http://beta.aebike.com/AEBike-40th-Anniversary-Jersey_p_54955.html

Comment: Need to see your HTML and js to give a meaningful answer. Will have a look tomorrow; in bed now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is provided  by the plugin. Just put your text in the relevant image's TITLE attribute.  Here is a code snippet from the plugin's demo page:

```
<a class="group1 cboxElement" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked at the examples more thoroughly, but didn't think there was a provided way based on the main documentation.

Comment: I just installed colorbox 1.6.3 and the title content is displayed over the page numbering in my case. I had to specify a larger width to work around that.